# Preventing ModelBuilder model from working on/after particular date?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, modelbuilder

I am working in ModelBuilder in ArcGIS Desktop.
I want to stop models from working when the current Time is greater than the project over time. Below snap showing where I am making a mistake.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: Are you wanting the Calc. Value date compare to identify if the Field Calculation runs or not?  If so, hook that process to the result of the Continue object.

Comment: I tried but not work

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested this but you could try using an `if` statement in a Calculate Value tool to issue a `sys.exit()` if today's date is greater than the date you want your model to cease working.

Then make that tool element a precondition to the rest of your model running.

Alternatively, as [commented by @BERA](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/278822/preventing-modelbuilder-model-from-working-on-after-particular-date/282257#comment447188_278822):

> You could rename or delete the Toolbox (*.tbx file) using a script in
>   the operating system which executes at the desired date.

Comment: Thanks BERA , Sorry to say that, i am new in programming. I am core gis. Please can you help me to execute  this syntax.